# C# how to trigger a callback?

Tags: c#, delegates, callback

This is part of my code snippet.
I want to pass a callback function into test().
therefore, after calling the "del" delegate, the callback() can be trigger automatically?

Functions:

```
butOK_Click()  //when click the button, disable it
test()  //a wrapper function calling updateUI function
updateUI() // a long process function
callback() // a callback function enabling the button back
```

How can i do this?
Thanks

```
public delegate void updateUIDelegate(bool refresh);
public delegate void asyncCallback();            
//...
void butOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    butOK.Enabled = false;
    test();
} 
public void updateUI() {
    // long function....doing 10s
}
public void callback() {
    butOK.Enabled = true;
}
public void test() {
    updateUIDelegate del = new updateUIDelegate(updateUI);
    del.BeginInvoke(null,null);
    //??????????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plesse, try the following:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    button1.Enabled = false;
    BeginAsyncOperation(updateUI);
}
void BeginAsyncOperation(Action operation) {
    operation.BeginInvoke(OnAsyncCallback, null);
}
void OnAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
    if(result.IsCompleted) {
        if(!InvokeRequired)
            callback();
        else BeginInvoke(new Action(callback));
    }
}
//
public void callback() {
    button1.Enabled = true;
    // something else
}
public void updateUI() {
    // long function....doing 10s
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Please also take a look at the following article: [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a delegate to a function as a parameter.  So add a parameter to your method 'Test' of type 'asyncCallback'.  Then in the 'test' method you can just call the delegate method passed in.

Here is some sample code:

```
class MyClass {

    public delegate void updateUIDelegate(bool refresh);
    public delegate void asyncCallback();            

    private void butOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        butOK.Enabled = false;
        test(new asyncCallback(callback));
    }

    public void updateUI(bool refresh)
    {
        // long function....doing 10s
    }

    public void callback()
    {
        butOK.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void test(asyncCallback callbackMethod)
    {
        updateUIDelegate del = new updateUIDelegate(updateUI);
        del.BeginInvoke(true, null, null);

        if(callbackMethod != null) callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand correctly, but I think you want to re-enable the butOK button after updating the UI. If so, there are two solutions.

1) You may modify

```
updateUIDelegate del = new updateUIDelegate(updateUI);
```

into

```
var del = new Action(() => { updateUI(); callback(); });
```

I change `updateUIDelegate` into `var` here because the definition of updateUI actually doesn't match `updateUIDelegate`.

2) Refactor `callback()` to match the definition of `AsyncCallback`, and pass it as the parameter of `BeginInvoke()`. That is,

```
BeginInvoke(callback, null);
```

This is more elegant or official usage of `BeginInvoke`, but may require more efforts to refactor the code.